# ListView is showing only 1 data while there are 3 records coming in the listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I want a listview in a tabhost. My data is coming from the database. Through retrofit, I am getting 3 records from the database. I am passing these 3 records to the ListView Adapter that I have created. These records are coming till the constructor of Adapter but after that in the getView method only 1 record is accessed 3 times. I am not sure why this is happening.

This is my Post Activity:

```java
public  static final ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo> mProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
BaseURL baseURL = new BaseURL();
VendorPostAdapter pAdapter;
ListView mPostList;
public List<WorkProfilePojo> returnedList = new ArrayList<>();

String lv_vendorId = null;
public static String lv_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    lv_vendorId = intent.getStringExtra("lv_vendorId");
    Log.e("vendor id", lv_vendorId);
    lv_name = intent.getStringExtra("lv_name");


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    getRetrofit();

}

private void getRetrofit() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new RetrofitObject().getRetrofit();

    final WorkProfileforPostTabAPI mProfileAPI = 
retrofit.create(WorkProfileforPostTabAPI.class);
    final Call<ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>> mCall = 
mProfileAPI.getWork(lv_vendorId);
    mCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>> call, 
Response<ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>> response) {
            mProfiles.clear();
            returnedList = (ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>)response.body();
            WorkProfilePojo wp;
            Log.e("Teste2", 
returnedList.get(0).getLv_eventSubCategory());
            for (int i = 0; i<= returnedList.size()-1; i++){
                wp=new WorkProfilePojo();


wp.setLv_vendorWorkId(returnedList.get(i).getLv_vendorWorkId());

wp.setLv_eventSubCategory(returnedList.get(i).getLv_eventSubCategory());

wp.setLv_workDescription(returnedList.get(i).getLv_workDescription());

wp.setLv_numWorkLikes(returnedList.get(i).getLv_numWorkLikes());

wp.setLv_numWorkComments(returnedList.get(i).getLv_numWorkComments());

                mProfiles.add(wp);
            Log.e("retrofit profile size: ", 
String.valueOf(mProfiles.size()));
            populateListView(mProfiles);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo>> call, 
Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
        }

    });
}

private void populateListView(ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo> mProfiles) {
    mPostList               = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listVPost);

    Log.e("func prof size: ", String.valueOf(mProfiles.size()));
    pAdapter = new VendorPostAdapter(this, mProfiles, lv_name);

    mPostList.setAdapter(pAdapter);

}
```

This is my Adapter:

```java
public class VendorPostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo> lv_profiles = new ArrayList<>();
String lv_name;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public VendorPostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo> 
lv_profiles, String lv_name){
    this.context = context;
    this.lv_profiles =lv_profiles;
    this.lv_name = lv_name;
    Log.e("adapter name", lv_name );
    Log.e("adapter workid", lv_profiles.get(0).getLv_vendorWorkId());
    Log.e("adapter workid", lv_profiles.get(1).getLv_vendorWorkId());
    Log.e("adapter workid", lv_profiles.get(2).getLv_vendorWorkId());
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mtxtViewPartnerName;

    TextView mtxtViewEventCategory;
    TextView mtxtViewDate         ;
    TextView mtxtViewFillDescription;
    GridView mgrdViewPhotos        ;
    ImageView mimgLike             ;
    ImageView mimgPostProfilePic   ;
    ImageView mimgShare            ;
    ImageView mimgComment          ;

    ImageView mimgLikeThumb  ;
    TextView mtxtNoOfLikes         ;
    TextView mtxtNoOfComments      ;
    TextView mtxtComments;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lv_profiles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_post, parent, 
false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.mtxtViewPartnerName = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPartnerName);

        holder.mtxtViewEventCategory= (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewEventCategory);
        holder.mtxtViewDate            = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDate);
        holder.mtxtViewFillDescription = (TextView)     
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFillDescription);
        holder.mgrdViewPhotos          = (GridView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.grdViewPhotos);
        holder.mimgLike                = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
        holder.mimgPostProfilePic      = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPostProfilePic);
        holder.mimgShare               = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
        holder.mimgLikeThumb           = (ImageView)     
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLikeThumb);
        holder.mimgComment             = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgComment);
        holder.mtxtNoOfLikes            = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNoOfLikes);
        holder.mtxtNoOfComments         = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNoOfComments);
        holder.mtxtComments             = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewComments);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final WorkProfilePojo wp = lv_profiles.get(position);

    Log.e("getView name", lv_name );
    Log.e("getView workid", 
lv_profiles.get(position).getLv_vendorWorkId());
    holder.mtxtViewPartnerName.setText( lv_name );
    holder.mtxtViewEventCategory.setText( wp.getLv_eventSubCategory() );

    FormatDate lv_date = new FormatDate();
holder.mtxtViewDate.setText(lv_date.formatDayMonDateYr(wp.getLv_creationDate()));
    holder.mtxtViewFillDescription.setText(wp.getLv_workDescription());
    holder.mtxtViewFillDescription.setText(wp.getLv_workDescription());

    holder.mimgLikeThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, 
VendorWorkLikesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("lv_workId", wp.getLv_vendorWorkId());
            Log.e("postad workid", wp.getLv_vendorWorkId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.mtxtComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, 
VendorWorkCommentActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

This is my activity_post.xml wrapped in relative layout

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolour"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my content_post for line item wrapped in relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPostProfilePic"
        android:src="@drawable/profileicon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewPartnerName"
        style="@style/InputLable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgPostProfilePic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="partner Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewManageWork"
        style="@style/Keywords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Managed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewEventCategory"
        style="@style/InputLable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewEvent"
        style="@style/Keywords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtViewEventCategory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Event" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDate"
        style="@style/InputLable"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDescription"
        style="@style/Keywords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Work Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewFillDescription"
        style="@style/InputLable"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="XYZ" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewPhotos"
        style="@style/Keywords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="Photos" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grdViewPhotos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewPhotos">

    </GridView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
        android:layout_below="@id/grdViewPhotos"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dividerlayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLikeThumb"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/grdViewPhotos"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/likethumb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewNoOfLikes"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="0" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewNoOfComments"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewComments"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Comments" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
        android:layout_below="@id/dividerlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dividerlayout1"
        android:layout_below="@id/dividerlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLike"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/likeicon2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewLike"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
            android:text="Likes" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShare"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shareicon3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewShare"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
            android:text="Share" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgComment"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/commenticon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewComment"
            style="@style/InputLable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
            android:text="Comment" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


From retrofit results, I am getting 3 records from database:
func workid:: W00000000000013
func workid:: W00000000000014
func workid:: W00000000000015

But in getView() method I am getting only 1 record coming 3 times:
Likesad name: W00000000000013
Likesad name: W00000000000013
Likesad name: W00000000000013
```

Comment: hello first of all remove  populateListView(mProfiles); from loop and put it outside of for loop, have you used GridView view in your adapter item layout fill?, try to scroll your listview might be other item is there and only one item can be show at a time

Comment: I don't see the closing bracket of your for loop, please update your code first.

Comment: public  static final ArrayList<WorkProfilePojo> mProfiles = new ArrayList<>(); remove the final. also remove the populateListView(mProfiles); from loop.

Comment: populateListView(mProfiles); is outside the for loop only. Not sure why the closing bracket is not appearing.

Comment: tried removing final. but it is not accepting in holder.mimgLikeThumb.setOnClickListener method. Error is coming in accessing wp in intent.putExtra("lv_workId", wp.getLv_vendorWorkId());

Comment: @Navin: i scrolled the listview. there is no item. in the log that i am printing in getView() method  Log.e("getView workid", 
lv_profiles.get(position).getLv_vendorWorkId());, only 1 workId is printed 3 times.

Comment: In activity, `mPostList               = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listVPost);` but in xml `android:id="@+id/listView"`. They don't match, please make sure you post the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.mtxtViewDate.setText(lv_date.formatDayMonDateYr(wp.getLv_creationDate(getPostion()))); 
holder.mtxtViewFillDescription.setText(wp.getLv_workDescription(getPostion()));
holder.mtxtViewFillDescription.setText(wp.getLv_workDescription(getPostion()));
```

This Might work.

Comment: its not working as the function getLv_creationDate() is the getter method of pojo class which does not take any argument.